# define a macro that converts values between byte order

Tags: c, macros, x86-64, endianness

I want to create a macro that converts unsigned value `conv` to the opposite byte order of the current CPU. When not in a macro, it works well but let's say I want to do that as a macro. The compiler throws me an `implict decleration` when I try to use the macro. Take in mind that `cpu_to_be32` and friends is a kernel-space functions, afaik at least.

```c
#define be32_or_le32(conv)  do { #ifdef __LITTLE_ENDIAN \
            conv = cpu_to_be32(conv); \
        #elif __BIG_ENDIAN \
            conv = cpu_to_le32(conv); \
        #endif } while (0)

u32 x = 0x12345678;

/* Convert the CPU's default byteorder to the opposite one */
be32_or_le32(x); /* Implict decleration */
```

**Update:** The answer below works really well but only without the `do {} while (0)`, why when `do..` added an error is thrown?

```
#ifdef __LITTLE_ENDIAN
    #define be32_or_le32(conv) do { conv = cpu_to_be32(conv); } while (0)
#elif __BIG_ENDIAN
    #define be32_or_le32(conv) do { conv = cpu_to_le32(conv); } while (0)
#endif

int __init sys_kernelmod_init(void)
{
    u32 conv;
    u32 x = 0x12345678;

    /* Convert the CPU's default byteorder to the opposite one */
    conv = be32_or_le32(x);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Just use bit shifts and then you don't need to know if the CPU is little or big.

Comment: @Lundin Can you drop an example?

Comment: There are countless examples of such already on this site.

Comment: What's the reason to **swap** byte order no matter what?  Usually the conversion is between CPU order and either big- or little-endian, not "give me the reverse of the current byte order".

Comment: @AndrewHenle No worries I know how to use it correctly, I just try stuff.

Comment: @Lundin `cpu_to_*x*e32` is just a sample of dozens of Linux-defined functions to convert values between different byte-order and is used in many places by the kernel, probably if there were faster ways to do that with bit shifts then the kernel wouldn't bother to create those functions.

Comment: @Lundin How does the method of bit shifting knows how much to shift without knowing if the CPU is little or big, exactly? AFAIK, you must know the byte order of the CPU before using e.g. `cpu_to_be`, otherwise it'll be pointless.

Comment: Those are likely macros expanding to shifts. The thing is, you don't need to know the endianess because you only swap the MS byte for the LS byte and so on.

Comment: Sorry, I missed it initially. Of course you cannot assign a `do...` to a variable. Also that is not how this macro is supposed to be used. It swaps the passed variable and does not have any return type. Use it like any `void` function: `be32_or_le32(x);`

Comment: @Gerhardh Yeah actually there's no need for the assignement in the macro, only using `cpu_to_be32(x)` works well, it returns the return value of the function, but I left it unchanged because that's what the OP of the answer did. But, `do { cpu_to_xe32(x) } while (0)` doesn't work either for some reason.

Comment: @ripab Macros in C do direct textual substitution.  With the "do .. while", your use of "conv = be32_or_le32(x);" becomes "conv = do { cpu_to_xe32(x) } while (0);", which is clearly a syntax error.  The "do .. while (0)" idiom is for multi-line macros that are used as statements, not functions returning a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have preprocessor conditionals *inside* the macro expansion text.

Switch the structure to:

```c
#ifdef __LITTLE_ENDIAN
#define be32_or_le32(conv) do { conv = cpu_to_be32(conv); } while (0)
#elif __BIG_ENDIAN
#define be32_or_le32(conv) do { conv = cpu_to_le32(conv); } while (0)
#endif
```

Comment: `expected expression before ‘do’`

Comment: @ripab then you are using that macro in a place where `do {  } while(0)` is not allowed. You do not provide enough code to judge what is wrong.

Comment: The removal of the `do { } while (0)` works well, as we don't use more than one statement. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Gerhardh `conv = be32_or_le32(conv)` is all I have done.

Comment: @ripab Where is that code located? Inside of a function? On file scope? What is in the lines before?

Comment: @Gerhardh Simply inside a function. Lines before are just the declartion of `conv` as well as assignement.

Comment: @ripab Don't describe your code. Show it. Without seeing what you really did we cannot tell why `do ... while` is not valid there.

Comment: @Gerhardh Give me a minute, I'm actually really wondering why it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use macros for things like this - use "static inline" functions.  And try to give more sensible names - you are swapping the bytes in the 32-bit value, so it is a "byte swap" function.  It is completely independent of the endianness of the system as you are always reversing the endianness, so there is no need to do any kind of conditional compilation.  And stick to the standard type names (such as "uint32_t"), not home-made names (like "u32"), unless you have very good reason.

```
uint32_t bswap32(uint32_t x) {
    return ((x >> 24) | ((x & 0x00FF0000) >> 8) | ((x & 0x0000FF00) << 8) | (x << 24));
}
```

Any decent compiler will optimise this to a single instruction if the target processor has a byte-swap instruction.

Comment: `uX` is a linux-specific data types that match a specific size but yeah if I would want to port to a different Unix system then I'd use `uintX_t`

Comment: `cpu_to_be32` returns a `u32` data type as well so.

Comment: Indeed, GCC and clang do optimize this (https://godbolt.org/z/49rEbKa41), so you don't actually need `__builtin_bswap32` ([GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html)) as long as you don't care how slow the code is with optimization disabled.  As long as the optimizer doesn't get confused with surrounding code and maybe split this up, and defeat its pattern recognizer...  But if you were using GNU C features, you'd `#include <endian.h>` (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/endian.3.html) for functions like `htobe32` and `htole32`.  And/or `<byteswap.h>`

Comment: @ripab Linux has many fine qualities, both as an OS and in its source code.  Its use of "u32" and similar types is not one of them.  The Linux kernel predates C99 and the standard names uint32_t, etc., so it has a good excuse.  However, you should still consider using the standard names - taking consistency and familiarity of other programmers into account.

Comment: @PeterCordes If the code is Linux-specific, then it is IMHO entirely reasonable to use gcc extensions like __builtin_bswap32.  (Other Linux compilers such as clang and icc support the great majority of these extensions.)  But the suggestion of using #include <byteswap.h>, and then the Linux macro bswap_32(), is perhaps even better.